# Конечное положение курсора при вводе сниппета в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

После указания последней ключевой точки курсор переходит на строчку после сниппета. Можно ли сделать, чтобы курсор оставался на месте последней ключевой точки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось конечное положение курсора задаётся с помощью `$0`